Apache Airflow: Module not found
I'm trying to run my first DAG inside airflow docker container, but airflow tells me it cannot find my personal libraries.
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/datacatalog.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/datacatalog.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Extractors.RestApiExtractor import RestApiExtractor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Extractors'

I have following project structure:

docker-compose
Dockerfile
src

dags
Extractors



In the DAG floder I have DAG with following import
from Extractors.RestApiExtractor import RestApiExtractor

But airflow seems not to see that module
Here is docker-compose:
version: '3'  

x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.10.2}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth,airflow.api.auth.backend.session'
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__ENABLE_HEALTH_CHECK: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER: /opt/airflow/dags  
    PYTHONPATH: /opt/airflow/DBConnectors:/opt/airflow/Extractors:/opt/airflow/MTL:/opt/airflow/MTL/CommonTLLibraries:/opt/airflow/MTL/MtlWorkflows  

  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/src/dags:/opt/airflow/dags  
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/src/logs:/opt/airflow/logs 
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/src/config:/opt/airflow/config 
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/src/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins 
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/src/DBConnectors:/opt/airflow/DBConnectors 
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/src/Extractors:/opt/airflow/Extractors  
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/src/MTL:/opt/airflow/MTL 
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/src/MTL/CommonTLLibraries:/opt/airflow/MTL/CommonTLLibraries 
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/src/MTL/MtlWorkflows:/opt/airflow/MTL/MtlWorkflows  
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:7.2-bookworm
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8974/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.providers.celery.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}" || celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_MIGRATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/src:/sources  

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:

What could be the problem?
